# GRAPH: Generate sum of squares between 1 and 10 for polynomial graph

Tags: python, sum

In an attempt to write a query in Python that will generate the first one hundred sums of squares between one and ten, the following attempt is made:

```
for a in range(1, 10): 
    for b in range(1,10):
        print(a**2+b**2)
```

Format should look like this:

```
1   1   4   9   16  25  36  49  64  81  100
4   5   8   13  20  29  40  53  68  85  104
9   10  13  18  25  34  45  58  73  90  109
16  17  20  25  32  41  52  65  80  97  116
25  26  38  34  41  50  61  74  89  106 125
36  37  40  45  52  61  72  85  100 117 136
49  75  53  58  65  74  85  98  113 130 149
64  65  68  73  80  89  100 113 128 145 164
81  82  85  90  97  106 117 130 145 162 181
100 101 104 109 116 125 136 149 164 181 200
```

After reading that the sum of two squares in a polynomial will always be positive, it occurred to me that it would make a good dataset to have all the numbers that could be generated by the sum of two squares.   Polynomial like (a+b)*(a-b)...

Seems to me there should be an answer that creates a couple of matrices multiplied together.

So tried this but format is wrong (Thank UnsignedFoo for the help)

```
df=pd.Dataframe=([])
for a in range(1, 10):
    val_row = " ".join([str(a**2+b**2) for b in range(1,10)])    
    print("{}\n".format("["+val_row+"]"))  
    df.append("{}\n".format("["+val_row+"]"))
```

It can be hard coded a line a time:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [2,5,10,17,26,37,50,65,82,101]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5,8,13,20,29,40,53,68,85,104], [10,13,18,25,34,45,58,73,90,109]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[17,20,25,32,41,52,65,80,97,116], [26,38,34,41,50,61,74,89,106,125]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df4 = pd.DataFrame([[37,40,45,52,61,72,85,100,117,136], [75,53,58,65,74,85,98,113,130,149]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df5 = pd.DataFrame([[65,68,73,80,89,100,113,128,145,164], [82,85,90,97,106,117,130,145,162,181]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df6 = pd.DataFrame([[101,104,109,116,125,136,149,164,181,200], [126,125,130,137,146,157,170,185,202,221]], columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df1.append(df2)
df1.append(df3)
df1.append(df4)
df1.append(df5)
df1.append(df6)
```

And at that point can be graphed and it would be great if the matrice could be built with less work - up to this point, Excel does everything but the Excel doesn't have the advanced matplot libraries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
xs=df1['A']
ys=df1['B']
zs=df1['C']
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs,ys,zs,s=50,alpha=0.6,edgecolors='w')
ax.set_xlabel('A')
ax.set_ylabel('B')
ax.set_zlabel('C')
plt.show()
```

A better example that is closer to where this should go is:

```
X = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
Y = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = (X**2 + Y**2)# R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)

plt.show()
```

Still hoping someone can answer this question.  I'd like to delete and start again: the "answers" don't address the issue of graphing.

Comment: `range()` is a little weird in python.  `range(1, 10)` actually only includes 1-9.  See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range

Comment: Thanks...  that makes sense

Comment: Would still be nice if I could get an answer on this - about the graphing portion...  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error with your code is, that after a for loop a `:` followed by a newline is required:

This results in:

```
for b in range(1, 10):
  for a in range(1,b):
    print(a**2+b**2)
```

Please note this still does not print your table, as print always generates a newline in python.

Comment: Your solution shows some of the values.  Maybe if the list goes into a dataframe it may produce a better format.   Plan is to graph it.   Something more like raw_data = {
        'X': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'Y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['X', 'Y'])

Comment: Is there a way to redirect this question since it is really about the graph and there is no solution here for the graph, only the math.

Answer (score 2):

```
for a in range(1, 11):
   val_row = " ".join([str(a**2 + b**2 -1) for b in range(1,11)])
   print("{}\n".format(val_row))
```

Output:

```
1   4   9   16  25  36  49  64  81  100

4   7   12  19  28  39  52  67  84  103

9   12  17  24  33  44  57  72  89  108

16  19  24  31  40  51  64  79  96  115

25  28  33  40  49  60  73  88  105 124

36  39  44  51  60  71  84  99  116 135

49  52  57  64  73  84  97  112 129 148

64  67  72  79  88  99  112 127 144 163

81  84  89  96  105 116 129 144 161 180

100 103 108 115 124 135 148 163 180 199
```

Comment: df=pd.Dataframe=([])
for a in range(1, 10):
    val_row = " ".join([str(a**2+b**2) for b in range(1,10)])    
    print("{}\n".format("["+val_row+"]"))  
    df.append("{}\n".format("["+val_row+"]"))